# Drawback of using static local variables and static functions on some platforms

Tags: c++

Quote from:
https://skypjack.github.io/2019-02-14-ecs-baf-part-1/

```
class family {
static std::size_t identifier() noexcept {
    static std::size_t value = 0;
    return value++;
}

public:
    template<typename>
    static std::size_t type() noexcept {
        static const std::size_t value = identifier();
        return value;
    }
};
```

> This is the code required to generate the identifier for a given type
>   when needed:

```
const auto id = family::type<my_type>();
```

> The drawback of this implementation is that it makes use of static
>   local variables and static functions. **Therefore, it doesn’t work
>   well across boundaries on some platforms.** On the other side it’s
>   straightforward and quite easy to use and to understand.

I have no idea why it doesn't work well on some platfroms?

What was meant by "across boundaries"?

Comment: because of the guarantee of the static keyword. every time you use that, you have to check if you have already set the value, otherwise initialize it

Comment: @Berto99: You mean some overhead introduced each time local static is accessed?  This is why it doesn't work well on some platfroms?

Comment: if you care about the 1% improvement in speed, or you are running in a very low energy / power device (which often happens if you are using C++), than yes, every time you access that variable, you also need to check whether you have already initialized it. Branch prediction will help, but there is always a small overhead

Comment: @Berto99 ok, i got your point.  Not sure this is what the author meant, but argument is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a static called id and a 3rd party library also has a static called id then they will conflict with each other.  Therefore it is better to scope things as tightly as feasible and stay within the bounds of your namespace.

Comment: I think this not answers the question. "on some platfroms" was not taken into account.
Statics are local in code example. So local static scope is limited. const auto id =  family::type<my_type>(); is just an example of generator usage. Scope of id is unknown in this example and id itself is not a subject of disscution.